# ng-clip not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs

Has anyone used ng-clip before and does not work in Internet Explorer? If yes, kindly share your solution. Thanks!

Basically, what i've done is the usual setup of the ng-clip documented here in http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-clip